# How to pass environment variable to gradle build file managed by Intellij IDEA

Tags: macos, gradle, intellij-idea, environment-variables, macos-big-sur

Environment: macOS BigSur

I have a gradle project which going to use private repository to fetch artifacts. To use such repos I need to supply gradle with credentials. Those credentials are temporal by nature, so I need to regenerate them from time to time. To do it I've tried to fetch credentials from environment variable.

```
repositories {
  maven {
    url 'https://***.codeartifact.***.amazonaws.com/maven/***'
      credentials {
        username "***"
        password System.getenv('CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN')
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried to set this credentals via ~/.bash_profile & ~/.zshrc

When I'm running gradle commands via terminal, it works. But when I try to reload gradle projects via IDEA UI, it fails to lookup the environment variable.

[image]

Looks like IDEA use something that ignores standard terminals configs.

Just for curiosity I've tried to highlight environment variables that available for gradle build. So I've added `print(System.getenv())` to build file. When I reloading projects via IDEA UI it outputs:

```
[PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin, JAVA_HOME:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home, COMMAND_MODE:unix2003, VERSIONER_PYTHON_VERSION:2.7, LOGNAME:*******, XPC_SERVICE_NAME:application.com.jetbrains.intellij.ce.117113.118030, __CFBundleIdentifier:com.jetbrains.intellij.ce, SHELL:/bin/bash, USER:*******, TMPDIR:/var/folders/vf/thcas1g120g1df3brgb9h50w0450gp/T/, SSH_AUTH_SOCK:/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.fa3tDAbfDE/Listeners, XPC_FLAGS:0x0, __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING:0x1F6:0x0:0x2, LC_CTYPE:en_GB.UTF-8, HOME:/Users/*******]
```

I guess something set this environment variables, but it's not clear how to set custom one.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Helped for me:
I added variables in `/etc/launchd.conf` file.
Now Gradle from Intellij IDEA work correctly.

see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/146047/17551.